# For loop and dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

In Python 3.x, I understand that by default, if we iterate over a dictionary, the loop variable is assigned the value of the key each iteration.
As such:

```
for loopvar_1 in {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}:
 print(loopvar_1)
```

results in

```
a
b
c
```

What benefit does it serve to assign the key to the loop variable instead of the actual values associated with that key (the numbers 1, 2 and 3 in this case.)

And so following from what I asked above, if we necessarily do need to refer to the key each time how can we iterate through the values without using any functions or methods?

Comment: The key is going to be unique and can be used to lookup the associated value. If it returned the values (which could all be the same) - you wouldn't be able to tie it back to the key...

Comment: Please don't roll back legitimate edits - if you have multiple questions, ask them separately.

Comment: If you want the values, it is not hard to do: `for key, val in {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}.items()`

Comment: yeah, since that returns both the key and the associated value which in turn can be assigned

Comment: @jonrsharpe I rolled back the edit so I could specifically avoid any responses that detailed any methods and functions, since I had expected this to happen  -_-

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed in [PEP-234](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/), which defined the behaviour of [dictionary iterators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/#dictionary-iterators) (emphasis mine):

> There has been a long discussion about whether
>
> ```
> for x in dict: ...
> ```
>
> should assign *x* the successive keys, values, or items of the
>   dictionary. **The symmetry between `if x in y` and for `x in y` suggests
>   that it should iterate over keys.** This symmetry has been observed by
>   many independently and has even been used to "explain" one using the
>   other. This is because for sequences, `if x in y` iterates over *y*
>   comparing the iterated values to *x*. If we adopt both of the above
>   proposals, this will also hold for dictionaries.

Comment: Of course, that assumes you agree that `in` should test if `x` is a key, not a value.

Comment: @chepner presumably that was already the case at the time of the PEP. Also it's way more efficient to find a key than a value in a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

One way to bring out all the associated values is to use the default method to refer to an associated value, and doing so inside a for loop so that the key used to call the associated value is changed each time.

```
mnm={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
for z in mnm:
    print(mnm[z])
```

PS:This was what I additionally wanted to know when asking the question, unfortunately the part about 'not using a method or function' was edited out as irrelevant.

Comment: There is a pretty big difference between asking "Why is python this way?" and asking "How can I do this in python?"

Comment: Yes I won't deny, my bad . I just started and was having some trouble phrasing it.

Comment: At this point I don't even know what I'm unaware of so my questions and the changes I make turn out to be somewhat absurd at times